# Hapi server having 403 errors with GET route

Tags: node.js, hapi

I'm trying out a hapi back end to serve up some files via HTTP GET requests. I'm a newbie with javascript but have a lot of programming experience (embedded C, Python etc..)

I have a simple method that can serve files:

```
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/file/{param*}',
        handler: {
            directory: {
                path: '/mydata/'
            }
        }
    });
```

And this can serve up any file from /mydata/ if I know the path via: http://localhost:3000/file/hello.jpg for example

But when I create a custom method to serve up files based on a year, month and day and a string match to get a certain file I get 403 errors:

```
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/api/getTMFile',
        handler: async (request, h) => {
            try {
                const year = request.query.year;
                const month = request.query.month;
                const day = request.query.day;

                if (!year || !month || !day) {
                    return h.response({ error: 'Missing year, month, or day parameters' }).code(400);
                }
    
                const directoryPath = Path.join(baseJmagDir, `/${year}/${month}/${day}/`);
                const files = fs.readdirSync(directoryPath);

                console.log('files %s', files);
                // Filter files based on a specific pattern
                const matchingFiles = files.filter((file) => file.startsWith('JMAG_TM_ascii_'));

                if (matchingFiles.length > 0) {
                    // Serve the first matching file found
                    console.log('matching files %s', matchingFiles);
                    const fileToServe = Path.join(directoryPath, matchingFiles[0]);
                    console.log('file to serve: %s', fileToServe);
                    return h.file(fileToServe);
                } else {
                    return h.response({ error: 'File not found' }).code(404);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
                return h.response({ error: 'Internal Server Error' }).code(500);
            }
        }
    });
```

Request: http://localhost:3000/api/getTMFile?year=2024&month=01&day=27 via Postman get 403 errors.

I have added some console logging and the code is finding the correct files at the correct path but won't serve them. It can't be a file permissions problem as I can access the file using the simple GET method so I'm wondering if this more elaborate method has some built-in security thing which I'm not disabling?

Am I missing something obvious here? Any help appreciated!